# Angular unit testing: Function not being called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test my service and cannot seem to get it working.  The concept is that when `setEmployees()` is called with an empty array, the service fetches employees from the server.

**Service**

```
  setEmployees( employees : Employee[] ) {
    console.log("Setting employees...", employees)
    if (employees && employees.length) {
      this.employees.next(employees)
      this.storage.set('employees', employees);
    } else {
      this.getEmployees().subscribe()
    }
  }

  getEmployees() {
    console.log("getting employees...")
    let url = `${this.base_url}/employees`;
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(url).pipe(
      tap(employees => {
        console.log("got em", employees)
        this.setEmployees(employees)
        this.storage.set('employees', employees)
      })
    )
  }

  returnEmployees() : IEmployee[] {
    return Object.assign([], this.employees.getValue())
  }
```

**Test**

```
it('should set employees correctly', fakeAsync(() => {
  let dummy = [{id: 1, name: 'Jeremy'}, {id: 2, name: 'Paige'}]
  spyOn(employeeService, 'getEmployees').and.returnValue(of(dummy));
  employeeService.setEmployees([]);
  tick();
  expect(employeeService.returnEmployees()).toEqual(dummy)
}))
```

**Test Response**

```
Expected $.length = 0 to equal 2.
Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object({ id: 1, name: 'Jeremy' }).
Expected $[1] = undefined to equal Object({ id: 2, name: 'Paige' }).
```

It's also worth noting that the `console.log()` statements don't occur in the expected order.  When running this test I see the following in the console:

```
getting employees...
Setting employees... []
```

...when I would've expected to see:

```
Setting employees... []
getting employees...
got em [{id: 1, name: 'Jeremy'}, {id: 2, name: 'Paige'}]
Setting employees... [{id: 1, name: 'Jeremy'}, {id: 2, name: 'Paige'}]
```

Clearly something isn't firing as expected but I'm not sure where the issue lies.

Comment: in your Service what is the definition of "employees" from  `this.employees.getValue()` ?

Comment: `employees = new BehaviorSubject(<IEmployee[]>[]);`
`employees$ = this.employees.asObservable()`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few catches with the test of async functions, your snipped seems susceptible to some of them...
I would suggest a more standard usage of Observables. And using [ReplaySubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) to keep the latest employee Array value in the service. Something Like:

service:

```
employees$ = new ReplaySubject<Employee[]>(); 

setEmployees( employees : Employee[] ) {
  if (employees && employees.length) {
    this.employees$.next(employees)
  } else {
    this.getEmployees()
  }
}

getEmployees() {
  let url = `${this.base_url}/employees`;
  return this.http.get<Employee[]>(url).pipe(take(1))
         .subscribe(employees => this.employees$.next(employees))
}
```

your test:

```
it('should set employees correctly', done => { // the 'done' helper function ensures necessary async callbacks are waited for
  let dummy = [{id: 1, name: 'Jeremy'}, {id: 2, name: 'Paige'}]

  employeeService.setEmployees(dummy)

  employeeService.employees$.subscribe(employees => {
    expect(employees).toEqual(dummy) // you might want to do a better element comparison here
    done()
  })
}))
```

Comment: Hmm.. after implementing this, I still the console.logs in the incorrect order and the test fails.  The value of `employees` within your subscription is empty.

Comment: sorry, missed a "return" on getEmployees()... it is updated now